# foreach loop to access each nested array row

Tags: php, html, arrays

I need to echo the following array values into a table but can only get the right output for the first row [0]

What is the syntax to loop through each row from the nested array.  When I simple echo $days it puts both values side by side in the same

Loop php

```
    foreach($inputs['course_details']['course_name'] as $courses){ 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>" . $courses . "</td></tr>";
    echo "<td>Days and Times</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    foreach($inputs['course_details']['days_times'] as $days){

            echo $days[0];

    }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
    };


"course_details" => array:9 [▼
"days_times" => array:9 [▼
  "monday" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 0
    1 => 1
  ]
  "tuesday" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 0
    1 => 1
  ]
  "wednesday" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 0
    1 => 1
  ]
  "thursday" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 0
    1 => 0
  ]
  "friday" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 0
    1 => 0
  ]
  "saturday" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 0
  ]
  "sunday" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 0
  ]
  "start_time" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "00:00:00"
    1 => "11:00:00"
  ]
  "end_time" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "17:00:00"
    1 => "14:00:00"
  ]
"course_name" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "Course 1"
    1 => "Course 2"
   ]
]
```

Gives me the following:

```
Course 1
Days and Times  0000011 00:00:00 17:00:00

Course 2
Days and Times  0000011 00:00:00 17:00:00
```

How do I loop through each row of values from the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `$days[0]` dynamic or change every run. The first time it runs, you want it to be as it is, but you want `$days[1]` the second time, `$days[2]` the third time, etc.

The easiest way to do this is to add the `$key` variable in the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop. The first time the key will be `0`, the second time the key will be `1`, etc.

To implement this, just use the following code:

```
foreach($inputs['course_details']['course_name'] as $key => $courses){ 
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>" . $courses . "</td></tr>";
  echo "<td>Days and Times</td>";
  echo "<td>";
  foreach($inputs['course_details']['days_times'] as $days){
    echo $days[$key];
  }
  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";   
};
```